# Show that eigenvalues of a matrix A are real only if $a^2+b^2\ge c^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Demonstrate that eigenvalues of a matrix
$A= \begin{bmatrix}
a & b+c\\
b-c & -a 
\end{bmatrix}$
are real only if $a^2 + b^2 \geq c^2$

Comment: Hint: the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Any idea or effort?

Comment: One of the $b-c$ should probably be $b + c$?

Answer (score 0):

If one of the $b - c$ is $b + c$. Consider the characteristic polynomial. We have
\begin{gather*}
  \chi_A(\lambda) = (a - \lambda)(-a-\lambda) - (b-c)(b+c) = 0\\
  \lambda^2 = a^2 + b^2 - c^2
\end{gather*}
The equation has real solutions only when the RHS is nonnegative. So $a^2 + b^2 \geq c^2$.

Comment: Yes, the upper one is b+c.Thanks, I got the same solution $λ^2=a^2+b^2−c^2$, but didn't know how to explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Following Jonathon Gai's comment gives

$0= \det (A - xI) = -(a - x)(a+x) - (b-c)(b+c)$

which means that

$x^2 - a^2 - (b - c)(b+c) = 0$

so

$x^2 = a^2+b^2 - c^2$

and the conclusion follows.